# Nextjs github actions deployment to netlify

Tags: next.js, github-actions, netlify, netlify-function, netlify-cli

I would like to deploy a Nextjs website (called enchanting-elf-d42f40 on netlify)  using the CLI, through GitHub actions but for now, I’m still getting this error when I want to access it:

> Page Not Found : Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.
> [NotFoundError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwts7.png)

To do this I’m creating a new site on the netlify UI, linking it to my GitHub repository, but afterward, I’m disabling the builds since I want them to be triggered through the CLI.
My `netlify.toml` :

```
[build]
command = "npm run build"
publish = ".next"

[[plugins]]
package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"
```

My `production.yml` :

```
name: Build & Deploy to Netlify
on:
push:
branches:
- master
pull_request:
types: [labeled, opened, synchronize, reopened]
jobs:
build-deploy:
if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'ci skip')"
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Use Node.js version from package.json
uses: actions/setup-node@v3
with:
node-version-file: 'package.json'
- name: Npm install
run: npm ci
- name: Build
run: npm run build
- name: Deploy to Netlify
uses: netlify/actions/cli@master
with:
args: deploy --prod --dir=.next
env:
NETLIFY_SITE_ID: ${{ secrets.NETLIFY_TEST_SITE_ID }}
NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

No functions are created on the deployment logs on the netlify UI, there are only files that are uploaded. I also tested the `-—build` option for the CLI but it changed nothing.

Example with no CLI deploy, the build is done through netlify UI on another site (everything works):
[Log Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhlht.png)

Example with the CLI (code above) :
[Log not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5FG7.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Already tried :

- `--build` option on netlify CLI (with `npm run build` and `next build`)
- remove the plugin in the `netlify.toml` since it can be auto-detected by netlify
- using the `nwtgck/actions-netlify@v2` package instead of the official from netlify